# Upgrade to KeyCloak 18 fails

Tags: mariadb, ext4, keycloak

I have a KeyCloak 17.0.1 that is apparently working without issues on my server, configured to use MariaDB. I say "apparently" because, as of today, it's not in production yet, albeit it starts in production mode, but it is on a development server and it is actually there only to let us developers play with it. I start it with this command:

```
bin/kc.sh -v start --hostname=my.real.hostname --https-certificate-file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.real.hostname/cert.pem --https-certificate-key-file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/my.real.hostname/privkey.pem --db-url-host localhost --db-username root --db-password my-real-password --proxy=reencrypt --db-schema=KEYCLOAK
```

It's running on a Debian 11 system with a Debian-packaged MariaDB server. In order to have it running, I had to move MariaDB data on a case insensitive ext4 filesystem and configure MariaDB to ignore case in table names (see [my post here](https://groups.google.com/g/keycloak-user/c/3hemmPcTcsk/m/6v7VkDIeAAAJ)). Before that, it was complaining with `Schema "KEYCLOAK" not found` error message.

Now I'm trying to upgrade KC 17.0.1 to KC 18, following [this guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/index.html), but when I start KC 18, I get [this error message](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/quyosudego.sql) (in short `Schema "KEYCLOAK" not found`).

Since KC 17.0.1 was complaining with the same error message and the problem was solved by moving MariaDB on a casefolding ext4 filesystem, I wanted to ensure that MariaDB was still  ignoring case. So I tried manually executing, from the MariaDB console, the same SQL statement that was causing the KC error message:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE TABLE KEYCLOAK.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

which replied with a different error message than what KC reports in the logs:

```
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'databasechangeloglock' already exists
```

so KC 18, during the upgrade process, is trying to create a table that already exists. Maybe it thinks it does not exist because it can't find the `KEYCLOAK` schema for some reason and it tries to create it, but then again how did KC 18 understood it needed to upgrade the database, if it could not find it? I'm not really looking for an answer to this: I'd be happy with just a workaround.

Just to make sure MariaDB is actually casefolding both schemas and tables names, here are some other things I tried:

```
# mysqladmin -u root -p variables | grep lower_case_table_names
| lower_case_table_names                                   | 2   
# mysql
MariaDB [(none)]> create database TESTDB;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> drop database testdb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> drop database nonexistingschemaname;
ERROR 1008 (HY000): Can't drop database 'nonexistingschemaname'; database doesn't exist

MariaDB [(none)]> create database TESTDB;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> use testdb;
Database changed
```

So MariaDB seems to work correctly (at least from the casefold point of view), but still KC 18 crashes on startup, while KC 17 works. Any clues?

Comment: i dont know what keycloak is or what it is used for, but most applications have a migration file for the database because in nearly any case, the db was, or, will be changed for a new version

Comment: @djdomi agreed, but I don't understand what that brings to the table.

Comment: in many cases you need to run first either a command or a special file first that missing entries will be created

Comment: I see, but in this case the official upgrade guide linked in my question does not state to run anything like that. In fact KC18 tries to update the database schema automatically on the first run.